# ruby Invalid UTF-8 character "\xA0" (Sass::SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby, symfony, encoding, utf-8, sass

I'm trying to run sass command

```
 sass /usr/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/sass --load-path /opt/lampp/htdocs/kunstmann/vendor/kunstmaan/admin-bundle/Kunstmaan/AdminBundle/Resources/public/scss
```

and I'm getting this error.

```
/usr/bin/ruby:1: Invalid UTF-8 character "\xA0" (Sass::SyntaxError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:373:in `block in check_encoding!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/util.rb:604:in `rescue in block in check_encoding'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/util.rb:601:in `block in check_encoding'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/util.rb:600:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/util.rb:600:in `each_with_index'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/util.rb:600:in `check_encoding'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/util.rb:654:in `check_sass_encoding'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:372:in `check_encoding!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:339:in `_to_tree'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/exec.rb:349:in `process_result'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/sass:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

I'v tried putting 
@charset "utf-8";
to the beginning of sass files.
Also tried to include Encoding.default_external = "utf-8" to numerous config.rb files.
ruby version ruby 1.9.3p484

UPDATE:

I'm getting css files compiled but with this error inside them.
compiling with Symfony2 command: app/console assetic:dump

```
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
[message] An error occurred while running:
&#039;/usr/bin/ruby&#039; &#039;/usr/local/bin/sass&#039; &#039;--load-path&#039;     &#039;/opt/lampp/htdocs/kunstmann/vendor/kunstmaan/admin-bundle/Kunstmaan/AdminBundle   /Resources/public/scss&#039; &#039;--scss&#039; &#039;--cache-location&#039;  &#039;/tmp&#039; &#039;/tmp/assetic_sasspqLusY&#039;

Error Output:
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/600d657f6ac2358f30ba6bc0ab4cd7ffb6194ced/assetic_sasspqLusYc20141111-4656-uxy3yg.lock
```

Use --trace for backtrace.

Comment: can you turn on showing whitespaces in your IDE and check if you don't have any weird characters there?

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the ruby program /usr/bin/ruby as an argument to sass. So sass is trying to read the ruby program which is a binary file, and that is why you are getting the error.

remove sass from the beginning of the command.

Comment: please take a look. i've updated my question. running test command without sass goes forever